# How to compare a variable to multiple values (case insensitive)

Tags: c#, comparison

I have a variable which expects multiple values (3 know values **irrespective of the case (upper/lower)**). I know we can use string builtin method like `compareTo/equals` or a `regex.ismatch` methods but I want to avoid using regex as I know what values to expect
I am wondering how we can compare this in `c#`
ex:

variable name: `word`, values: `bcj or jnkll or gd` (case insensitive)

```
word.substring(0,5) == "bcj" || word == "jnkll" || word == "gd" 
(not sure how to have this ^^ case insensitive)
        or
    Regex.IsMatch(word, values) (want to avoid regex)
```

Comment: `class` is a keyword, can't use `class` as a variable name.

Comment: Have you considered using an enum instead of a string or is that not a valid option?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values in a `HashSet<string>` and can specify the string comparer to use (either `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` or `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`):

```
var values = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "bcj", "jnkll", "gd" },
                                 StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
string word = "gd";
string input = word.Length <= 5 ? word : word.Substring(0, 5);
if (values.Contains(input)) {

}
```

Other variant

```
if (input.Equals("bcj", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
    input.Equals("jnkll", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
    input.Equals("gd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
}
```

But probably the simplest method is to convert the input to lower case

```
string word = "JnKll";
string input = (word.Length <= 5 ? word : word.Substring(0, 5)).ToLowerInvariant();
if (input == "bcj" || input == "jnkll" || input == "gd") {

}
```

Or simply `.ToLower()` to use the current culture.

Note that `Substring()` throws an exception if either the start index or start index plus length specify a position not within the string.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you may have already answered your own question? Just use `.Equals`.

You've got a string of values to check, separated by `/`.

so should be able to do

```
string values = "bcj/jnkll/gd";
string actualValue = "bcJ";

foreach (string valueToCheck in values.Split('/'))
{
    if(actualValue.Equals(valueToCheck, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        // do whatever you need to do
}
```

Otherwise i'm not really sure what you're question is

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will not have the variable values defined like `bcj/jnkll`. That is just an example. Instead of using `foreach` is there anyway to do this in a single line comparison (without using many builtin methods)

Comment: @user25799752 why do you want to do this without Regex or a foreach, what are you trying to gain here? You need to be more specific if the examples you are giving are not real examples. If you know the values, why do you need to check? What are you trying to do here?